# Custom provider getting execude on every request with Spring 6 Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently working on upgrading my web application from Spring Boot 2 to Version 3. As Spring Boot 3 uses Spring 6 I needed to update my security configuration. After my changes I noticed that my custom authentication provider is getting called on every request which leads to heavy database traffic. It's not happening if I use the spring default login form but with basic authentication.

Here is my sample security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My Provider looks like:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if ("admin".equals(username) && "admin".equals(password)) {
            var user = User.withUsername("admin").password("admin").authorities(new ArrayList<>()).build();
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new
                    BadCredentialsException("system authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Behavior in short:

| SecurityConfig | Behavior |
| --- | --- |
| `.formLogin()` | 1x Login / Provider-Call |
| `.httpBasic()` | 1x Login per Session / 1x Provider-Call per request |

What can I do to get the old behavior back as it was with Spring 5 / Spring Boot 2?

Comment: Why do you need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` in its own `AuthenticationManager` why doesn't the default `AuthenticationManager` work, and use the default database authentication provider?

Comment: It is just a placeholder implementation. At this point I do a user authentication against my database + ldap.

Comment: so why dont you use the default Database authentication provider? your placeholder implementation does not explain your user case

Comment: i can't go into details here but it's neccessary.

Comment: well then im not going to do guesswork when trying to solve this when you are not allowed to know the boundries. The solution to your problem is, use the built in features of the framework. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone having the same issue, you can restore the old session behavior by setting the session creation policy in your security filter chain:

```java
.httpBasic(withDefaults())
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
...
```

Comment: Would it not be better to write it as follows: `.httpBasic(withDefaults())
.sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                      sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy..IF_REQUIRED))
...`